# What does this function mean?

Tags: scheme, racket, lambda

for the following function:

```
(define (update f x v)
  (λ ($x)
    (display $x)
    (newline)
    (if (equal? $x x)
        v
        (f $x))))
```

1. what does `$` mean here?
2. where does the `$x` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` has no particular meaning in Scheme -- it's just a character like any other.

As for part 2: the code

```
(define (update f x v)
  (λ ($x)
    (display $x)
    (newline)
    (if (equal? $x x)
        v
        (f $x))))
```

is equivalent to:

```
(define (update f x v)
  (define (DUMMY $x)
    (display $x)
    (newline)
    (if (equal? $x x)
        v
        (f $x)))
  DUMMY)    ;; Return the lambda
```

So `$x` is just a parameter to the inner function, nothing special.

Comment: All right. No particular meaning..... Then what about question 2? Where is this `$x` binding?

Comment: Freezdom:  To answer question of the type "Where XX bound?" you can get help from your tools. Enter your program in DrRacket, click the "Check Syntax"-button, and then hover the mouse over the binding you want to know more about. (An arrow should appear). Now try right clicking to see the options available.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, the `$` has no syntactic meaning, it's merely part of the parameter's identifier (like a variable name).  This appears to create an anonymous function with `$x` as its only parameter.